# Create a Column to Count the Number of Occurances of Each Item in a Power Apps Collection

Tags: powerapps-collection

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of each item in a PowerApps Collection.

SharePoint List Name: Product

Desired Result

Fruit    Number of Occurrences
Apple            1
Orange           1
Apple            2
Banana           1
Orange           2
Apple            3
Banana           2
Banana           3
Watermelon       1
Apple            4

I DO NOT Want the Items Grouped. I would like the Items shown Exactly as I have displayed it where  each item in the collection is counted based on the number of times it appears in the collection

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further? What is the purpose of the output? Would it simply be displayed somewhere on your screen as a label or it would be reused like a derivative table?

Comment: The output would be displayed in a gallery. Once it it displayed, I will be exporting the data from the gallery into a csv table using Power Automate

Comment: This is a bit confusing. What do you mean exporting from the gallery? You don't need a gallery for exporting data. Also, you say number of occurrences in a collection but in your desired result you have duplications.